# How to enable auto format code in eclipse?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml, eclipse-juno

I have tried to format  `xhtml`  code in `eclipse IDE - Juno` using the shortcut by two ways. which are

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

   I did't get any solution from this.
2. <kbd>menu</kbd> --><kbd>Source</kbd> --><kbd>Format</kbd>

   I am not able to find <kbd>Format</kbd> under <kbd>Source</kbd> also, instead it showing only three options. see clear image in below.

   [image]

what is the problem with my `Eclipse IDE`? What i have to change in settings?

Comment: You need to switch to the java perspective.

Comment: Already i am with `Java EE` perspective .!!

Comment: I usually use manually to format eclipse or don't use it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you need to associate the `.xhtml` file type to an Editor.

1. Open `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`.
2. Find `.xhtml`.
3. Associate the `Web Editor` to the `.xhtml` file type.

Then try to re-format again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Already i have associate with web editor.. even though i removed & added it again.. Now it works fine.!!

Comment: On Mac : ⌘ + ⇧ + F